# My static folder is not working in production mode / Nuxt js

Tags: javascript, docker, static, nuxt.js, dev-to-production

## In Footer.vue

[image: Footer code]

## In nuxt.config.js

[image: Config code]

I can't donwload files and can't see my favicon.ico from static folder
nuxt 2.15.7

In docker logs I have a https request to my backend api https://mywebsite/web/v1/categories/privacy_policy_ru.pdf

But it's incorrect because I have all this files in my static folder

[image: Request data]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.